404 when launching ASP.Net core web applications from Visual Studio 2022
This is the first time installing VS2022 on this computer.
Any new projects I have tried launching from Visual Studio seems to launch without error but when I try to load the application through the browser I just get a 404 error.
Here is my launch configuration although, I get the same issue when launching a new core web app...
{
  "profiles": {
    "Kestrel": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5238"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DotNet Commandline": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "run --configuration Debug",
      "workingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\jcarr\\Workspace\\ProductionOutageTracker\\Web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:36511",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}

I have tried various launch configurations without success. I have tried creating a brand-new application and I have the same problem, so I don't believe it's anything in my program.cs that is failing.
The only thing I have found that works is using the dotnet run command, which I can setup in launch configurations and launch from Visual Studio but then my debug breakpoints gets the error "symbols have not been loaded for this document"

Hi Jason, may I know if you have a chance to clear visual studio caches for testing.

If it still not works, please open the visual studio installer and update the vs2022 to the latest version. If the issue still occurs, could you create a brand new project and share with us, thanks.

which of these launch profiles do you have selected in VS? there are 3 profiles in there.

assuming you are using the "Kestrel" profile, it seems you only configured the http port. In your app, do you have UseHttpsRedirection? perhaps try to specify https port as well to see if it makes a difference, it would look something like "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7277;http://localhost:5041"

also can you elaborate on I have tried creating a brand-new application and I have the same problem? are you really not able to start a brand new asp.net core web app?

can you check the output window in VS to see if there are any errors? are you sure your app is running before you make a request?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JasonPan Updating VS2022 resolved this issue. Thanks!

@JasonCarr Please allow me summarize my comments as answer below, thanks

For this kind of issue, upgrading visual studio to the latest vesion is the first choice.
If upgrade to latest version not helps, then we can try to clear the cache.
The last step is reinstall the visual studio.
